# gcloud emulator rapidly filling up all Docker disk space

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run

EDIT 4: I've opened up an issue for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219164388

---

I'm using the Google Cloud Run emulator (`glcoud beta code dev`), and it works fine...

...until after I've used it for a few days, it has consumed all of the hard disk space that I've allotted to Docker (60 GB!) and fails to run anymore.

I then manually force-clear Docker's disk space using `docker system prune --all --force --volumes`.

**Is there a way to tell `gcloud` to automatically clear out all the files it has written when shutting down the emulator?**

Maybe a flag I'm missing?  Or maybe I'm shutting down the wrong way?  I'm currently stopping the emulator by `ctrl+C` from the terminal.

EDIT 3: As pointed out in the answer below, what I need is the equivalent of the `docker --rm`, but for gcloud.

---

EDIT: In case it helps, I think I have an idea of what's causing the fill-up:

I'm using GCR to serve a webpage, and in my Dockerfile.  Every time I make changes, the gcloud emulator rebuilds the container.  I think that with each rebuild, it's re-copying all the assets (images, audio), which is why it eats up so much disk space.

---

EDIT 2: Docker shows `glcoud-local-dev` as `in-use` even after I've `ctrl+C` shut down the emulator from the command line.

Comment: The Docker **--rm** will not help you. The issue that you have is that containers are not a single file. They are a collection of layers. Layers are kept (sort of like a cache) to speed up future container builds. The cached layers (artifacts) are not deleted unless you **prune** the system. Do not use **force** when pruning. You have a free disk space problem, solve that so that you are not worrying about how much space Docker is using. On development machines, you do not want to even think about it unless necessary. To follow StackOverflow guidelines, ask one question per post.

Comment: For the **prune** command, there are different types of objects to prune. Images, Containers, etc. Read the documentation so that you understand how container images work to help you solve problems like this. https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Comment: Google Cloud provides a build service so that containers are built in the cloud and not on your development system. https://cloud.google.com/build

Comment: For your last problem, reboot the system.

Comment: @JohnHanley this is a question about the local (not cloud) GCR emulator, which uses your local docker.  There is only one question, in bold above: Is there a way to tell gcloud to automatically clear out all the files it has written when shutting down the emulator [rather than having to do?  The other information is just clarifying to the nature of the problem.  I don't have memory issues with the container itself, just with the gcloud emulator implementation.

Comment: OK - you know your environment better than I do.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you may use the following command to remove all unused containers, volumes, networks, and images at once:

```
docker system prune -a -f --volumes
```

If that isn't enough, one can start by removing operating containers:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q) docker system prune -a -f --volumes
```

Using a different site with additional space is also a viable option for resolving this issue.

Currently, the best practice for this is to run the following command: `docker system prune`

Before you accept the consequences, take note of the output from this command:

> WARNING! This will remove: - all stopped containers - all networks not
> used by at least one container - all dangling images - all dangling
> build cache Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]

To put it in another way, continuing to use this command is irreversible. Keep in mind that the recommended practice is to treat [stopped containers as ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers), which means you should design your Docker job to avoid keeping them around. If you're not actively debugging your containers, you might wish to use the [--rm flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm) at runtime.

According to [gcloud beta code dev](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/code/dev), it does not mention any flag yet that can prevent your main issue.
Please consider that this command is currently in BETA and may change without notice. It was last updated on 2021-10-19.

This variant is also available:
[gcloud alpha code dev](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/code/dev)

Comment: I would indeed like to treat stopped containers as ephemeral, but to do that, I need the equivalent of the `--rm` flag for `gcloud beta code dev`.  It doesn't seem like there is such a flag or configuration option, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Looking for more information to get a similar command of --rm for gcloud beta code dev, I found the following:

To clear up a development environment, use this command [gcloud beta cloud clean-up](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/code/clean-up). This command can also be used to delete any artifacts left over from failed development environments.

For the gcloud beta code dev, I did not find any similar flag, but remember this could be due to the BETA status.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like there's not an "automatic" cleanup mode -- you need to either do it manually from docker or gcloud.  I guess that would be a good feature request...

Comment: Do you happen to know how to submit FR's for the `gcloud` CLI?  It's not on GitHub, so I'm not sure where to report something like this.

Comment: According to the documentation I found, it’s not possible yet.
To create a feature request, here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with the instructions on how to create one.

Here is also the direct link to Open Cloud SDK Issues, which is [List Open Google Cloud CLI Issues](https://b.corp.google.com/savedsearches/559662).

Comment: Thanks, I opened up an issue there! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219164388